# How to add a table relationship using pyodbc

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

So I have two tables within a Ms Access database that have a common GUID field which I can use to link the two.  I would like to create a relationship using the common GUID without having to open up MS Access and create the relationship.  I was hoping I could do this with pyodbc since I'm running a pyodbc query already that needs the relationship in order to work correctly.  Is this even possibly using pyodbc?

(Incomplete) DDL for existing objects:

```
CREATE TABLE Customer ( CustID GUID NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY );
CREATE TABLE FileList ( FileID GUID NOT NULL );
```

What is the syntax for creating a foreign key relationship between the `Customer` and `FileList` tables, and how can this relationship be created using `pyodbc`?

Comment: The real question is "can I express this in SQL"?  Unless I'm misunderstanding your question the answer is yes.

Comment: For relationship you are looking for the [CONSTRAINT clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177889%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You would do this by constructing an ALTER TABLE command and sending that command to the database.

The exact syntax of that command depends on what kind of relationship(s) you're creating.  You'll probably need to create both a PRIMARY KEY on the "one" side of the relationship and FOREIGN KEY on the "many" side.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I agree what you stated here.  But unsure on the syntax to use.  I add some more information up under More Specifics in my answer above.  In reading up on Alter Table, seems like I may need to create an Index but not sure if I'm following that correctly.